# Azure AD B2C with MSAL and Angular redirects to login page immediately after logging into the app

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an Angular app that uses ASP.NET core Web API. I used ADAL for authentication but now the app should also be accessible to customers and hence I removed the ADAL code and added MSAL related code. I created an Azure AD B2C tenant and used those credentials in the app. When I run the app now, I am redirected to Microsoft login page which is perfect. But when I login after entering email and password, it logs into the app and immediately redirects me to the login page again. I don't get time to even debug the issue in Dev tools. The code in msal.service.ts file is below

```
private applicationConfig: any = {
    clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    authority: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    b2cScopes: ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'],
    redirectUrl: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};

private app: any;
public user: any;
constructor() {
    this.app = new UserAgentApplication(this.applicationConfig.clientID, this.applicationConfig.authority,
        (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {
           console.log(token);
        }, { redirectUri: this.applicationConfig.redirectUrl });
    // this.app.redirectUri=this.applicationConfig.redirectUrl;
}

public login() {
    let tokenData = '';
    this.app.loginRedirect(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(data => {tokenData = data; });
}

public getUser() {
    const user = this.app.getUser();
    if (user) {
        return user;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public logout() {
    this.app.logout();
}

public getToken() {
    return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
        .then(accessToken => {
            console.log(accessToken);
            return accessToken;
        }, error => {
            return this.app.acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
                .then(accessToken => {
                    return accessToken;
                }, err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        });
}
```

The code in auth.service.ts is shown below

```
constructor(private msalService: MSALService, public jwtHelper: JwtHelper) { }

public getToken(): string {
    const token: string = window.sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken');
    return token;
}

public login() {
    const token = this.getToken();
    if (token == null || token === undefined || token === 'null') {
        this.msalService.login();
    }
}

public getTokenDecoded(): any
{
  return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.getToken());
}
```

I spent a lot of time on this but unable to identify the exact cause of the issue. Please help me out with this

Comment: See this demo app for [loginRedirect w/ Angular](https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal)

Answer (score 2):

To debug these problems turn on `preserve log` in the console and network tabs:

[image: console window screenshot]

[image: network tab screenshot]

---

There is probably an error returned in the URL which should be visible in the network tab.

ex:

> https://jwt.ms/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90161%3a+A+self-asserted+send+response+has+failed+with+reason+%27Internal+Server+Error%27.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+bc145550-912a-4f35-b833-334cf1ace96d%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-01-08+01%3a48%3a43Z%0d%0a

Comment: I turned on the 'Preserve log' as you mentioned and tried to run the app again. Now, I have an error in console that says 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at MSALService.login'. It fails at the line

this.app.loginRedirect(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(data => {tokenData = data; });   My b2cscopes are also correctly mentioned and I don't know what is causing the iisue

Comment: Oh, I see now.  After ‘loginRedirect()’ remove the then.

Comment: I removed it and tried but now the page doesn't load and after sometime it says page unresponsive

Comment: Yeah, there are some other problems with your logic.  See that sample app I referenced.  Let me know how it goes.  Post a follow up after reviewing it :)

Comment: Sure. I shall go through it and let you know

Comment: I downloaded the sample app you mentioned and followed the steps to set it up. To start off, i am trying to set it up with the tenant 'fabrikamb2c' used in the app. In the readme file, it says  set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to "http://localhost:6420" and also  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Development". How do I actually set them from command line?